# Rails validation errors when try save records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

i have a code in controller:

provider_earning_files_controller.rb

```
  @pefRecord = ProviderEarning.new(
      provider_id: row["id"],
      provider_earning_files_id: 4,
      amount: row["amount"],
      description: row["description"],
      date: params[:to]
    )
```

provider_earning.rb

```
class ProviderEarning < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :provider
  belongs_to :provider_earning_file
 
end
```

provider_earnings_file.rb

```
class ProviderEarningFile < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :file
  has_many :provider_earnings
end
```

When i run @pefRecord.save i get the error message

```
Provider earning file must exist
```

but the id = 4 yes exist! in records Provider Earning
how to solve? i use a ROR 6+

Comment: maybe `provider_earning_file_id` not `provider_earning_files_id`

Comment: ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError (unknown attribute 'provider_earning_file_id' for ProviderEarning.):

Comment: Then your database is wrong. It should be `provider_earning_file_id`. If you really want it to be `provider_earning_files_id`, then you need to tell rails about your choice.